# Explanation for theorem: There's a unique linear transformation defined for a base.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> **Theorem**: 
>   Let $V$ and $U$ be vector spaces on a field $K$. $V$ is of
>   finite dimension $n$. $B =$ {$v_1, v_2, ..., v_n$} is a base for $V$.
>   $u_1, u_2, ..., u_n$ are any vectors in $U$.
>
> There's a unique transformation $T$: $V \rightarrow U$ such that $T(v_i) = u_i$; $i$=
>   $1,2,...,n$.

So that's the first theorem on the Linear Transformations chapter of my Linear Algebra course. I do understand that for the vectors in the base there's a unique $T$. But I don't understand the scope of this theorem.

I'd like to know if this theorem only applies for the vectors belonging to the base $B$, or if it applies to all vectors in $V$ expressed in terms of that base.

Please, add anything you think could help at improving my understanding of this theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain of $T$ is the entire vector space $V$.  Because, as you seem to realize, each member of $V$ can be expressed as a unique linear combination of the members of $B$.  So if $$v=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_iv_i$$ then $T$ is defined so that $$T(v)=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_iu_i$$

Answer (score 0):

The key is that $T$ is *linear* (which you left out of your statement of the theorem, though you mention it elsewhere). If you know $T(v_i)$ for any set of vectors $\{v_i\}$ whatsoever, then you also know the value of $T$ applied to any linear combination of them. In particular, if $\{v_i\}$ is a basis for the domain of $T$, then the result of applying $T$ to any element of the domain is completely determined by its values on those basis vectors.